# List content types using views in Drupal6 (Views 2)

Tags: views, 6, nodes

Is it possible to generate a list of all the content types in use using Views?
I would also like to restrict the content types that are listed.
I want to get the machine-readable-name of each content type and will then use the 'Views Custom Field' module or something to expand on each item.

Comment: Views 2 or Views 3?  I don't know the answer, but it may matter here.

Comment: "url of each content type" does not exists per se. URL to add node of that type? URL to view?

Comment: @MPD - views 2 ---

Comment: @Molot, what I really meant was the 'Type' (the machine readable name). I.e. as would use in URL like: none/add/<content-type-name>